# Google maps directions works locally but not from web server

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the site http://www.houston.ind.br/api/map/map1/rota.htm as an sample to develop something similar.  Things go ok when I run the thing from my local file system using firefox but when I upload the page (either mine or the one referenced above) to a server it no longer works.  I tried substituting a google key I had obtained for use with the google api but that makes no difference.

I looked through the enabled APIs for my key and turned almost everything on to no avail.

Any idea what's going on?  Do I need some other type google key?

Comment: the linked page works for me However...you should update your code(you still use V2-code)

Comment: Try copying it to another server.

Comment: why don't you upload it to another server?

Comment: Moderators fell free to delete this if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by changing http to https on the following line

```
<script src=" https://maps.google.com/?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=ABQIAAAAA9cb-iZ2XyrDiJe40QcIixSYNaUY3kVpdSwiLlIjooxsqEAfDxQTzxBRZuWS5Ya5YKFT2LGaMMA-IQ"
      type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style='overflow:hidden;height:292px;width:1286px;margin-left:0.7cm; padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; '>
<div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:292px;width:1286px;'></div>
<style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style>
</div> 
<a href='https://embedmaps.org/'>Baal vattika</a> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=a3c2ec770a2f881655fbdd614aa3d259bdbd1e89'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function init_map(){
  var myOptions = {zoom:12,center:new google.maps.LatLng(13.0649666,80.22328349999998),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.0649666,80.22328349999998)});
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>Baal vattika</strong><br>51B, 2nd St, Gill Nagar, Choolaimedu, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600094<br>600094 chennai<br>'});
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});
   infowindow.open(map,marker);}
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```